# How to redirect url with question mark in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to change this URL:

```
site/nossos-socios.php?termo=test
```

to

```
site/nossos-socios/?q=test
```

I've already tried to use **\?** before **q** but doesnt work, this is my rewriterule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^nossos-socios/q\=([^/.]+)?$ nossos-socios.php?termo=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `RewriteCond` to match a query string:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(nossos-socios)/?$ $1.php?termo=%1 [NC,L]
```